# qml - Disable Switch with a Timer

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Problem: I have a switch that needs to be disabled for around 50 seconds at the start of the program and then re-enabled.

When my timer ends is there some sort of way to tell me it ended so I can re-enable the switch? Or is there a way to do this without using a timer.

Thanks in advance!

```
 Timer {
        id: delaySwitch
        interval: 50000;
        running: true;
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            mySwitch.enabled = false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you tell him to tell you when the timer ends?

Comment: @eyllanesc by that i mean when the timer reaches the end of it's interval (50 seconds) I would like to re-enable the switch

Comment: What I understand is that the switch is disabled by default, after 50 seconds you want to enable it, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yup that is what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable your switch and using the triggered signal to enable it.

```
Switch{
    id: mySwitch
    enabled: false
}

Timer {
    id: delaySwitch
    interval: 50000;
    running: true;
    repeat: false
    onTriggered: {
        mySwitch.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I wasn't using the trigger signal properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it alternatively in a more declarative way:

```
Switch {
    id: mySwitch
    enabled: !delaySwitch.running
}

Timer {
    id: delaySwitch
    interval: 50000
    running: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also have it as self-destroying `Timer`

```
Switch {
    property Timer t: timer.createObject(this)
    enabled: !t
}

Component {
    id: timer
    Timer {
        interval: 50000
        running: true
        onTriggered: destroy()
    }
}
```

Don't ask me for the performance, though.
Probably, if used only once, the `Component` and the new class for the `Switch with property t` will use up more memory, than you free by destroying the `Timer`. Maybe, if you use this `Switch` tons of times, it might save you some memory. But afaik, a `Timer` is a really small object.